# How to add date to point?

Tags: point, linestring

I have a lot of points with a GPS tracker and I need to simplify them.

I create view (`location_view`) in PostgreSQL (with PostGIS):

```
 SELECT location.id,
    location.added,
    location.latitude,
    location.longitude,
    location.pulse,
    location.speed,
    location.device_id,
    st_makepointm(location.latitude, location.longitude, (location.id)::double precision) AS point
   FROM location;
```

I used SQL:

```
SELECT st_simplify(st_makeline(d.point), 0.0001) from location_view d
```

And next I got `LineString` value and brought line to the map. But `LineString` сontains only coordinates. I need date in point.

How to add date to Point/LineString?

Comment: do you have a date in the location table?

Comment: yes, column `location.added`

Comment: do you want to add the date to each individual point of your GPS track, or for the whole track one date?

Comment: to each individual point of my GPS track